# how to make the textview visible in button click event in android

Tags: android, button, textview

I developed one Simple app, which contains  one textview.and my problem is that I want visible in invisible this text view on button click event.

At loadtime I do this

```
myTextView.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

and after this at Button Click event, I do this.

```
myTextView.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
```

The textview  is visible but it is overlap on below TextView means myTextView cannot contain space. So what can I do now?

Comment: post your XML layout code here

Comment: in this app i use only layout in xml file.and all the code textview is make in java code runtime this code is belowtxtAnsBorrow = new TextView(myContext);
txtAnsBorrow.setId(k+2);
txtAnsBorrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ansBorrowlayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: we need that layout in xml file....

Comment: in this apps i use only layout in xml file and the textview is create in java code.

Comment: yes and we are asking for that layout in xml file only :)

Comment: ok but in java file it`s possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

`myTextView.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);`

instead of

```
myTextView.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

to **persist the space** in layout.........

Comment: but is that possible when i do is invisible(Use GONE) than the space is remove and when i use setVisible(View.Visible) than the space is reallocate its possible?

Comment: ok this is my layout file<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_poi_ipad"
    android:orientation="vertical" > </RelativeLayout>

Comment: are you adding the text field dynamically ?

Comment: yes use the java code and set the layout parameter according the device width and height

Comment: so adding the textview Relatively to each other ? means using RelativeLayout.addRule or simply adding them?

Comment: basically is there any there view which position depends on the view is going to hide..............

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relativelayout, specify `android:layout_below="id_of_above_text_view"` in the second textview.

If you dont specify the relation to the views in relative layout, it will appear one above other

Answer (score 0):

A slight change in your code should make it work fine I believe.

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and after the button click,

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For doing it in the java code, have a go at this(haven't tried it out myself though)...

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.setText("XXX");
rl.addView(iv,0);
rl.addView(txt,1);
```

Comment: i also do this but i want hide not only textview but also tetxview contain space?

Comment: In that case, go to your xml file and mention the attribute android:layout_below="idOfYourTextView" in the code of the component which is overlapping on top of the TextView.

Comment: but i never use the xml file for textview i create in java file it`s possible?

Comment: I am not sure if this would work but check the edit in my answer.

Comment: but i also use this.it`s not hide the space which textview contain

Comment: I myself use xml most of the time to define the layout parameters. Cant help you much if you dont use xml

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("A");
tv1.setId(1); 

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("B");
tv2.setId(2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());

layout.addView(tv1);        
layout.addView(tv2, lp);
```

and when you change visibility, call `invalidate()` on parent view of myTextView (layout here) or root view of your layout ( `layout.getRootView()` )

Answer (score 0):

This will show and hide the text(s) when the corresponding buttons are pressed.
Very useful if you want to control multiple text with buttons

1)XML File:

```
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >
                    <Button
                        android:text="The Origin"
                        android:id="@+id/btnOrigin"
                        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtOrigin"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/about"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_body"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >
                        <Button
                            android:text="Vision"
                            android:id="@+id/btnVision"
                            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVision"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/vision"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_body"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </LinearLayout>
```

2) JAVA code

```
        private TextView txtOrigin, txtVision;


        public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnOrigin:
                txtOrigin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOrigin);
                txtOrigin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtVision = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVision);
                txtVision.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
             case R.id.btnVision:
                txtVision = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVision);
                txtVision.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtOrigin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOrigin);
                txtOrigin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
                }
             }
```